# How to force a piece of code inside a thread to run uninterruptedly (keep it from being preempted by the OS)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

For a given task T, and blocks of code (wrapped in methods here) m1, m2 and m3,

is there a way to force any one of them - say m2 - to run uninterruptedly, i.e., that the thread running this program, upon reaching its time slice limit, if in the middle of execution of m2, do not leave the processor until m2 finishes, only then making room for a new thread ?

Is this possible ?

Example:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                m1();

                //I want to assure m2 runs uninterruptedly, i.e., that the running thread does not stop while executing m2
                m2();

                m3();
            });
        }

        private static void m1()
        {
            //whatever1...
        }

        private static void m2()
        {
            //whatever2...
        }

        private static void m3()
        {
            //whatever3...
        }
    }
```

Answering everybody's "why did you come up with this?", it popped up while trying to find a solution to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654380/multi-threaded-c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-automation-with-uris-not-known-beforeh) problem. What I thought: I need to guarantee that my switches from and to the main window handle is not interrupted/preempted.

Whether this is a plausible solution for my real problem or not - I thought the question was worth asking.

Comment: You can change the thread's priority, but it's rarely an appropriate thing to do.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that micromanaging CPU resource allocation to individual threads is too low-level for C#/.NET. closest I can think of is setting the Thread.Priority attribute, but this won't guarantee anything.

Comment: isn't thread priority related to process scheduling only ? Meaning, it affects when it will be scheduled, if before/after this or that thread... if so, does not help here. Beside the docs say that the OS is not obliged to follow the program definitions for priorities.

Comment: This really sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please explain the problem you are having that you think having a uninterruptable thread would solve, we may be able to give you a alternate solution that can be done.

Comment: As mentioned to Ramus below, this popped up with me trying to find a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654380/multi-threaded-c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-automation-with-uris-not-known-beforeh, while I wait for help :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that a preventing a thread from being preempted does *not* mean no other thread runs at the same time. All modern systems have multiple logical cores so even if `m2` runs uninterrupted that does not mean `m1` or `m3` cannot run *in parallel*, on other cores.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: yes Remus, I am aware of the this fact. Hypothetically, I was thinking about a single core architecture. But yes, these days modern systems have multiple cores, in which case you have parallelism added to multitasking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You are running your code on [preemptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) OS so there is nothing in your power to prevent preemption.

What is your *real* problem? Try to describe the actual problem you have, *why* did you come up with this requirement, and then perhaps one can offer advice to your actual problem..

After update

Remember this simple rule of thumb for multi-threaded programming: *threads are almost never the right answer, event driven programming almost always is*. Unless you have CPU intensive computation than can scale-up on distinct data sets, there is seldom a need to add threads. Spawning a new thread (or Task) simply to wait for IO (navigate to URL...) is an anti-pattern. Unfortunately 99.999% of multi-threaded programming examples simply use threads to simplify the control flow.

With that in mind, consider using an event driven model, for example [`EventFiringWebDriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_Events_EventFiringWebDriver.htm). You will only have one thread, you main thread, and react in it to your web driver events (URLs downloaded, tabs opened, etc etc).

Comment: Thanks Remus. Well, this "requirement" popped up with me trying to figure out ways to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654380/multi-threaded-c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-automation-with-uris-not-known-beforeh, while I wait for some help :-)

Comment: @Veverke I don't see how having a thread that can't be interrupted by the OS helps you with your other question. It looks like you just need to have beeter control of which threads access `webDriver` at the same time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: what I thought was: I need to guarantee that the switch to and from window handles is not interrupted. But if your point is right - that I should not be using a webDriver instance (assuming it is not thread save) inside threads, then indeed the answer will have nothing to do with this. In any case, I thought the question was worth it.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those situations where the correct answer depends on why you are trying to do what you are asking. Doing this right is much harder than it sounds.

In the general case, yes. There are ways that you can make that happen. However, I assume from the context that you are wondering if you can make that happen on a stock Windows OS. The short answer is no. Windows has a preemptively multi-tasking kernel, and there is a nothing a user process can do to prevent it from interrupting the thread when the time slice ends.

However, that's not the whole story. You can set your thread's priority to "REALTIME", which will keep it from being preempted by any other thread. The scheduler will still preempt you, but because no one else has a higher priority it will come right back to you. This [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx) explains how to do that.

Note that this is know to be **a bad idea.** If not properly managed it will take over the whole machine and bring it to a screaming halt.

For most users, it is suggested to use the [Multimedia Class Scheduling Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684247(VS.85).aspx)

If you really need real time services for your software (that is, being able to run something with hard guarantees about quality of service) you might look at real time extensions for Windows or Linux, or one of the fully real time systems like [vxWorks](http://www.windriver.com/products/vxworks/) or [QNX](http://www.qnx.com/).

Comment: Well, this then makes the current selected answer incorrect. Thanks for sharing. Regarding RealTime priorities, however, when you say it will keep the thread from being preempted - this will only be true if no other RealTime threads exist, right ? If so, you are saying that yes, it is possible - but unless (when talking about Windows) you have only one such thread.

Comment: Yes. Note that this is not the same thing as running without interruption, and in a multi-core system it will not achieve the goal you linked to in your question (because other threads could run on other cores at lesser priority and cause problems.)

Comment: Then your answer is inaccurate, you should not state, overall, that this is possible. Bottom line is that it is not, in the context of a preemptive OS, just like Ramus stated below.

Comment: In fact, this is possible. Just not in stock Windows. You did not limit your request to this case, so simply saying no would be incorrect. As of this writing, you still do not require the solution to work for stock Windows (as per your question.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. What do you mean with "stock Windows" ?

Comment: I mean a vanilla Windows system that the average user might have installed. There are third party tools and other versions of Windows which provide features that would make this possible. Also, other operating systems provide this built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Not without switching to a embedded version of windows that supports Real-Time Extensions. And even then you would need to switch from C# to a native language to be able to use those scheduling features.

The best you can do is change the [thread's priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx) during the execution of `m2` to make it *less likely* that it will get scheduled away. However if you are going to do that you should not use `Task.Run` and instead use a actual `Thread` object, you should not change priorities on a ThreadPool thread (which is what `Task.Run` uses).

Comment: Thanks for the insights, Scott.